# Using second eSATA port for second DAS

Tags: hp, hard-drive, esata

I have a server with a HP M60 12TB disk array attached.
The server and disk array both have 2 eSATA ports in order to connect 2 cables to double the throughput, but I am wondering if it is possible to use the second port to attach another disk array instead?

The documentation for the M60 had very easy information about how to set up the dual-connection for throughput, but did not mention my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean, an [HP MSA 60 Array Enclosure](https://web.archive.org/web/20080527095217/http://h18000.www1.hp.com:80/products/quickspecs/12627_div/12627_div.html)? And for cables, you're probably referring to an external multilane SAS SFF-8088 connector.

[image]

If so, then depending on which HP Smart Array RAID controller you're using, you can cascade up to *three* additional MSA 60 shelves off of one unit by using one port as IN (4) and the other as OUT (5).

*Cascading - The MSA60 has the unique capability of cascading up to 4 - four enclosures behind a single SAS port (depends on the Smart Array Controller).*

[image]
<sub>(source: [www1.hp.com](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/12627_div/12627_ov2.gif))</sub>